# Localized email recommendations currency

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, einstein-recommendations

I am using localized Einstein Email Recommendations and the currency is not being added, should this be added manually or should it work automatically indicating that something is wrong with my setup?
The productnames are all working in the right language.
The catalog doesn't contain the currency, just the price.

Code I am using:

```
 <a href="https://500009753.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5ea94444a575f20030fcfd1c/l/1/%%emailaddr%%?locale=nl-BE">
    <img src="https://500009753.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5ea94444a575f20030fcfd1c/i/1/%%emailaddr%%?locale=nl-BE">
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recommendation calls look correct, so I suspect the issue being in your catalogue. You need to include the currency in the locale specific price. Assuming following catalogue structure:

*SkuID|ProductCode|ProductName|locale_nl-BE_ProductName|locale_en-US_ProductName|Keywords|ProductLink|locale_nl-BE_ProductLink|locale_en-US_ProductLink|ImageLink|RegularPrice|SalePrice|OnlineAvailability|RegularPriceDisplay|locale_nl-BE_RegularPriceDisplay|locale_en-US_RegularPriceDisplay|SalePriceDisplay|locale_nl-BE_SalePriceDisplay|locale_en-US_SalePriceDisplay*

The content of *locale_nl-BE_RegularPriceDisplay*, in order to display the price as Euro, should be populated with: `99.99 &#8364;` - outputting: 99.99 €

Comment: Oh ok, so the currency should be in the field as well in the catalog? 

I thought just the number was fine and that marketing cloud would do the rest based on the locale.

Comment: Nope - you need to define currency in catalogue as well, @user3485470